# Python 2 and Python 3 - Running in Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

Having various projects in both Python 2 and Python 3 (with both python versions installed), I was looking for a more intuitive way to run scripts via Command Prompt than
`py -3 script.py`.

Python 2 already took `python script.py`, so ideally `python3 script.py` should invoke Python 3.

My question: How can I add `python3` as a Command Prompt command?

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/python2.7`
`#! /usr/bin/python3.5`

Comment: Most operating systems do this (`python`/`python3`) by default.

Answer (score 8):

If Python 2 and 3 are both installed and in the PATH variable, you can do:

py -2

or

py -3

Answer (score 6):

Searching did not yield good results, so I thought I should share the process I took with anyone looking for this in the future.

1. Make sure the Python 3 folder is present in the PATH environment variable.
2. Locate the "python.exe" file in the Python 3 folder.
3. Copy and Paste the "python.exe" file within the Python 3 folder.
4. Rename the copied file to "python3" (or whatever you want the command to be).

Now, when you input `python3 script.py` to Command Prompt, the script will run through the copied Python 3 file.

Also, by copying python.exe (instead of renaming it) you allow other interpreters - such as PyCharm - to continue using their default "python.exe" path settings.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

A "symlink" has the same effect, but keeps things a bit tidier.

Comment: Rather than copying the `python` executable simply create a [symlink](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

Comment: I'm fairly certain after some searching, I could find this exact solution elsewhere, but glad you solved it

Comment: ahh! This is not a good solution at all!  I'm glad it worked but (a) properly configuring your `%PATH%`, and (b) using the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) should be all that you need.  If for some reason it's not, then dimo414's suggestion of a symlink is much better.

Comment: The reason you want a symlink is that a "python3.exe" symlink will still be valid if "python.exe" gets replaced by an in-place upgrade. You don't have to remember to copy the file again. Just run `mklink python3.exe python.exe` in an administrator command prompt.

Comment: Ah! I had never heard of a symlinks before! Thank you for this information.

Comment: I wasted a solid 2 hours on this. I was using `subprocess.call` with 2 python versions installed (both in path), but creates all kinds of confusion as the subprocess module is so ambiguous to begin with. I just ended up creating a copy called python3 and used the direct path to that folder. Sighs.