# Maintaining and switching between different python interpreters on all mediums - best practices?

Tags: python, installation

I am looking for best practices for maintaining different python installations (or environments) simultaneously, specifically, with regards to achieving the following 3 objectives/requirements:

*Note: I am using Anaconda installation for Python*

### Requirements

**Requirement1** - *Jupyter Notebook convenience*

All python interpreters (either in different installations or environments) should be available in jupyter notebook in the list of kernels.

**Requirement2** - *Command line convenience*

On the command line it should be easy to specify any python interpreter available on my machine to run a py script, something like: 'py2 test.py' or 'py3_env1 test.py'

**Requirement3** - *Automation convenience*

Run the py scripts using the *.bat files, using any python interpreter available on the machine.

---

### Choices

As implicit above, there are 2 broad choices here:

**Choice1** - Single installation, multiple environments

...i.e. maintain a 'single' python installation folder but create multiple environments in it using 'conda'.

**Choice2** - Mulitple installations, single environment each

... i.e. maintain different python interpreters in separate installation folders with only the root environment.

If I make any any of the two Choices above, I can satisfy some, but not all 3 requirements.

For instance, if I make *Choice1*, I can satisfy *Requirement1* easily, but not 2 and 3; and with *Choice2*, I can satisfy *Requirement2* and *Requirement3* only. Details as below.

---

### Satisfying requirements

**Satisfying Requirement1** - *Jupyter Notebook convenience*

If I make *Choice1* (single installation, multiple environments), I can satisfy *Requirement1* using the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook). It suggests registering ipykernels in all of the environments.

With *Choice2*, is it possible for jupyter notebook to see all kernels spread across many python installations? I couldnt make it work.

**Satisfing Requirement2** - *Command Line convenience*

If I make *Choice2*, then I can satisfy *Requirement2* by using *Python Launcher* or creating *symlinks* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734521/python-2-and-python-3-running-in-command-prompt)

With *Choice1*, it doesn't work since *Python Launcher* doesn't recognise different environments (yet!). So, is there any other way to make it possible? Can I, lets say, use some kind of command alias, something like a short-cut command 'py' that refers to the 'root environment' *python.exe* file, and another one 'py2' that refers to another environment's *python.exe*. And if I do that, will calling 'py2' be robust in the sense that it will call correct *site-packages* folder? (Note, we haven't activated the environment here, so the windows 'PATH' may not point to the correct folders). I would assume that  activating the environment is necessary, but I am not sure.

**Satisfing Requirement3** - *Automation Convenience*

If I make *Choice2*, I can probably satisfy *Requirement3* using *Python Launcher* as well (just like above). Also, not to mention, my script can also use *shebang operator* to mention which python it wants to invoke. However, I don't want to hardcode the python version in the script and keep the flexibility in the command itself.

If I make *Choice1*, I thought that a *.bat file like below will work:
    conda activate py3_env1
    python test.py
    deactivate

So, I intend to activate the environment first and then call the py file. However, this doesn't work. Calling this bat file executes just the first line, activates the environment and then nothing happens.

---

So, in short, I am looking to have a consistent setup that allows me to invoke different python versions from all mediums - notebook, command prompt and automated bat files - very conveniently.

Any guidance or recommendation around best practices are very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: @e4c5 - I dont see any similarity between this post and the link you have mentioned. Yours is more like a virtualenv primer, mine is a set-up related question.